# jquery height and width after div rotation fails in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, rotation

I am using plugin http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate3.js for rotating div. After rotation i get correct height and width in IE but not in chrome. Please help. Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/73pXD/2948/

Comment: Usual to include the code in the question as well.  What height and width are you expecting, there are no sizes set on the object being rotated.

Comment: Please run this http://jsfiddle.net/73pXD/2952/ link in Internet Explorer and then in Chrome. It give changed height and width of the div after change in rotation degree in IE but in chrome it doesn't. So need some solution on this.

Comment: Ah, that issue - I've come across it myself.  Firefox agrees with Chrome.  IE is the only one that recalculates the bounding box for the rotation to the containing orthogonal rectangle.  The others retain the size of the box, as it has not technically changed, it is just rotated.

Comment: Dare say you will have to calculate it.

Comment: As long as you know the centre of rotation, then the true bounding box can be calculated.  Check where it is per browser.  Also, beware that the layout engine uses the assumptions about the bounding box too, so in Chrome and FF, you will find the areas outside the original bounding box overlay neighbouring things. IIRC